# Why does PuTTY use its own private key format when log into SSH server?

Tags: putty, private-key

Just a little bit curious, why PuTTY use its own version of private key format to do SSH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author of PuTTY gives two main reasons for having the custom key format on [this page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/key-formats-natively.html).

In short:

- PuTTY's format stores the public half of the key in plaintext, which allows PuTTY to send the public key to the server automatically.
- The key is fully tamperproofed with the help of a Message Authentication Code.